# Calling a service on input change and update view

Tags: angular

I'm writing a simple component which takes as input an Id and calls a service method to return an entity to display:

```
@Input() id: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.id != undefined && this.id != "") {
        this.detailSubscription=this.service.load(this.id)
            .subscribe(result => {

                    this.detail$ = result;
                    this.cd.detectChanges();
            });
    }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.cd.detach();
   this.detailSubscription.unsubscribe(); 
}
```

This componet works only the first time. If input Id changes it doesen't update the view.

I also tried to put service call inside `onChanges` method, but it won't works due to unsubscribe that is called only once on `onDestroy` method.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngOnInit` like below. As `ngOnInit` will fire only once, where as `ngOnChanges` will fire every time the input value changes.

And also try unsubscribing before calling service.

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

   if (changes['id']) {
      if(this.detailSubscription) {
         this.detailSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
      //call your service here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a getter/setter approach you can easily intercept the direct change of the id input property. For example:

```
private _id:string;
@Input('id')
set id(value:string){
   this._id = value;
   this.fetch();
}

get id(){
   return this._id;
}

 fetch(){
 if (this.id !== "") {
        this.detailSubscription=this.service.load(this.id)
            .subscribe(result => {

                this.detail$ = result;
        });
 }

}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.detailSubscription.unsubscribe(); 
}
```

Comment: Not a good approach when you have mulitple properties that can change. Can lead to frivolous/bad requests on init.